Keep linking of data in ETL staging from different sources
I am trying to build a small, manually written ETL process which loads data from different sources into a star-schema Data Warehouse (DWH), concerned about students from different universities. Currently, my approach is to first stage the data inside a staging area, which reflects in structure the DWH before actually loading non-redundant data into my dimensions and fact table. All databases / tables are located on a MSSQL server 2022.
A minimalized example of the staging area, to reflect the DWH, looks like this:
 CREATE TABLE [stage].[Stage_Performance]
(
  [ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  [Grade] INT NOT NULL,
  [ECTS] FLOAT NOT NULL,
  [StudentLocation_ID] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [stage].[Stage_StudentLocation](ID)
)

CREATE TABLE [stage].[Stage_StudentLocation]
(
  [ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  [Country] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  [City] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
)

The source systems all use their own database, therefore also having their own identity columns, etc. Given are two of my systems which hold the students location for the location stage table. One of them is using a separate table, one has it embedded into the entry directly as a single column.
University 1
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student]
(
  [MatrNr] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  LastName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  MiddleNames VARCHAR(200),
  FirstName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  MailAddress INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[StudentAddress](StudentAddressID),
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StudentAddress]
(
  [StudentAddressID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  Street VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  HouseNumber VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  Additions VARCHAR(50),
  ZipCode INT NOT NULL,
  City VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  Country VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

University 2
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student]
(
  [StudentID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  [MatrNr] INT NOT NULL,
  FullName VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  FullAddress VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL
)


What currently bugs me is, when loading the data into the staging area, how do I keep the linking between the different rows intact? To be more precise, when extracting from the staging area into the Warehouse itself, how can I best ensure that the linking for data of a single student of university 1 is correct and university 2 as well?
I thought about using the generated keys from the different source systems, however, as they are not synchronized, I would end up with duplicated values in a column which would lead to problems when extracting the data.
Additionally, I had the idea to not use a staging area made of multiple tables, but just a single one where all the data for a single student record is just a row, but as of now it seems to complicate the loading process from staging to the DWH itself.
As the goal for this projects is, at some point, to semi-automate the SQL-code generation for ETL, using services for ETL like Pentahoo, etc. is currently out of the question, sadly.
I am happy for any input on the problem. If I have messed up to describe precisely, on what is my goal to achieve, sorry for that.

Add ExternalStudentId and ExternalUniversityID and keep track of the source IDs that way perhaps?

You mean to add them to the staging table, where the combination of StudentID and UniversityID (or AddressID and UniversityID) would uniquely identify a record in staging?

Actually i was thinking both staging and production, because i guess you need to be able to merge the student records too? Or do you re-import it all from scratch?

The project (luckily) isn't concerned about differential loading, so that can be done away. Would that mean that it is now only concerned about staging to introduce both IDs?

Yeah, give it a spin and see if it works?

Thanks, I will try this out, maybe it does solve some things. It still, somewhat, bugs me that there are now two fields, or a single field with a combination of two elements + maybe a lookup table for the different universities. But if that is what it takes, why not try it.

Never combine two fields into one. You could i guess do the staging for each uni database separately, then you don't need to keep track of any external references, but not sure if it's better. And unless you're hosting alpha centaury's entirely student database, the extra size these fields add to your system shouldn't be too large.

The normal solution here is to

Stage each source in a separate table, as the schema may vary among sources.  You can stage them together if you control the source systems and keep their schemas in sync, and/or there are a large number of them.

Add "SourceSystem" and "SourceSystemID" as an alternate key to the target DW table in addition to a new surrogate primary key.


The alternate key (SourceSystem,SourceSysemID) is then used when you load from the staging table to the DW.  You need to join on this key to identify the existing rows in the DW table and UPDATE it, or INSERT if it doesn't exist.
When the schemas vary across source system, the DW table represents a "standardized" view across the different systems.  So you would map columns from each source to the standardized view.  And typically there would be some columns in the source that aren't used in the DW table.

See updated answer.

Thanks, I see. As this simple demonstrator system will basically only use bulk loading and reimport from scratch, so there is (luckily or not) no need to update, just insert distinct.
For the example with 2-3 different source systems, would you rather choose 1 stage table for each source or design a combined source (of multiple tables)? If it is the first one,I guess I'd need to transform from the stage to the DW table?
Edit: Wish I could upvote the answer.
